# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadablePartial

Tags: java, jasper-reports, classnotfoundexception

I'm using Eclipse Luna with Jaspersoft Studio plugin 6.2.2 to developer reports for web application. No problem to run one basic blank report from Eclipse plugin, but when I load this jrxml from java class, I receive the message:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/insurance] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.joda.time.ReadablePartial
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
```

I'm using the code:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fileName);
```

What's this error?

Answer (score 15):

Sounds like you're missing the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) dependency. GitHub project for Joda-Time available [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time).

As per documentation, to get the latest Joda-Time jar you can do:

[**Maven**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
  <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**:

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
```

Or you can manually download the latest jar from [here](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases) and add it to your classpath.